Unpack zip archive within gzip
I've got a directory of files, and those files used to be zip files. Due to a recent change outside of my control, the directory now contains gzip files with zips inside of them.
I was using this line of code to unpack a zip to my working directory:
shutil.unpack_archive(file, path_work + '\\' + file.stem, 'zip') where file is a pathlib Path.
How can I update my code to unpack the contents of the zip contained in the gzip file? Do I need to abandon shutil? I'd love to write out only the contents of the zip to the file system.
